# Are there any jQuery/javascript date pickers that work in this format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a calendar component that I am trying to interface with. I am building a form that will allow the user to add events by clicking on the cell.

The calendar is supplying the date like `Wed Apr 06 2011 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (EST)`.

To try and be user friendly I want to split the date, time and timezone and then preload the date into a text field with date picker. Then I would like to reformat the data back to the structure it came in so the event can be processed by the calendar.

I have used a few datepickers but non that use this format, is there a way i can easily convert this format to something usable.

Im sorry but i am not a javascript programmer so need a little extra guidance.

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: have you used jquery UI datepicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you might be looking at this.

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

also check this for date format

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-formats

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate

Answer (score 0):

DateJS is a great library that provides a plethora of options for parsing/formatting dates: http://www.datejs.com/

The jQuery UI Datepicker also provides a dateFormat option which allows you to specify the format for the text input behind the Datepicker: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

Trent Richardson has published an addon for jQuery UI to extend Datepicker with a time component: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by component, but the date is easily parsable

`var date = new Date(Date.parse("Wed Apr 06 2011 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (EST)"));`

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a direct javascript method to parse that data, do the following.

```
var $string = <that data string above>;
var $dateElements = $string.split(" ");
```

now $dateElements is an array that looks like the following:

```
{"Wed", "Apr", "06", "2011", "00:00:00", "GMT+1000", "(EST)"}
```

to get the month you'd type
`$dateElements[1]`

to get the hours you'd do

```
var $time = $dateElements[4].split(":");
var $hours = $time[0];
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp